# Prove this sum is always zero

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algebraic-topology, summation

I encountered this problem in the context of singular homology, trying to prove that the boundary map is always zero.

How do you show that the following sum, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, is always zero?

$$ \left[\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^{j+k} A_{k+1,j} \right]+\left[\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=k+1}^{n}(-1)^{j+k}A_{j,k}\right] $$ where $A_{l,m}$ are some numbers which depend on two indices.

I have written out the first few terms of each sum and verified that it is indeed zero, but I would like to make a clean change of variable that somehow clearly shows this. I would also like to avoid induction on $n$.

Comment: Without knowing what $A_{lm}$ are, you are asking for something that is too broad -- a general technique for proving statements, some of which might be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ \left[\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^{j+k} A_{k+1,j} \right]= \left[\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} (-1)^{j+k-1} A_{k,j} \right] $$

Let's change the letters of indice (just a change of name):

$$= \left[\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{j-1} (-1)^{j+k-1} A_{j,k} \right] $$

Let's invert both sums :

$$= \left[\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=k+1}^{n} (-1)^{j+k-1} A_{j,k} \right]$$
And finally
$$= - \left[\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=k+1}^{n}(-1)^{j+k}A_{j,k}\right] $$

Comment: Exactly what I wanted--thanks!